# How to align a text just below a button?

Tags: html, css

[image]I want to align a text just below a button but i'm unable to do so.I want forgot password below login buttonMy code is:

```
<div style="padding-top: 20px;clear: both;">
        <h2>Welcome</h2> 
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-group-xs bg-info"  style="color:white;float:right;margin-right: 20px;margin-top: 30px">Signup</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-group-sm bg-info"  style="color:white;float:right;margin-right:40px;margin-top:30px;">Login</a>

        <a href="#" style="font-size:20px;color:white;float: right;margin-right: 40px;margin-top:60px;padding-right: 40px; ">Forgot password</a> 

  </div>
```

Please help.

Comment: Please provide an example of your problem in the form of a https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: And don't forget to show what you've tried. If it is homework, you need to use the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. Keep both rows in separate `<div>`

```
<div style="clear: both;">
            <h2>Welcome</h2> 
            <div style="float:right;">
                <a href="#" style="color:white;margin-right: 20px;">Signup</a>
                <a href="#" style="color:white;margin-right:40px;">Login</a>
     </div>

    <div style="clear: both;float: right;margin-right:40px;margin-top:10px;">
    <a href="#" style="font-size:20px;color:white;">Forgot password</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the float element and set display: block.